# Not getting proper nodeValue

Tags: php, curl, nodevalue

I thought I had this working some time back, but I am finding its not working always properly and I am trying to sort why.

```
$resolver = new URLResolver();
$resolve= $resolver->resolveURL($site);
$resolved = $resolve->getURL();
$parsing = file_get_contents_curl($resolved);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($parsing);

$para = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
$firstparagraph = $para->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $firstparagraph;
```

I would expect the above return the content of the first instance of `<p>`. Usually this works, but not always.

Sometimes I am instead getting a return such as:

```
string(5335) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive Keep-Alive: timeout=15 Date: Sat, 26 Jan 2019 18:37:18 GMT Server: Apa..........
```

This specific output is being returned from `https://gener8ads.com/referral/?ref=test`

When I get the above output I find if I change to `item(1)` it properly returns `$firstparagraph`.

I am wondering why this is happening and perhaps I can write a proper check when it does happen so the correct first paragraph is returned. I realize in this instance I could just check the output for HTTP/ and if it exists move on to `item(1)`, but I don't know that will sort this problem indefinitely.

So the question is, whats causing it to return this instead of the first `<p>`?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have a custom function called `file_get_contents_curl()` that makes an HTTP request and returns the raw response (headers and body). Then you need to strip headers first because `DOMDocument` expects HTML—it couldn't care less about HTTP.

Comment: It is a custom function from https://gist.github.com/jesseleite/6181643 but its really just a replacement for `file_get_contents`- I use this on 99% of sites and it works exactly as expected. Its only certain sites that have this issue.

Comment: Also if it was actually getting headers, `$firstparagraph = $para->item(1)->nodeValue` wouldn't work either.